# Why does Jerry ask for only an $80k ransom, when he owes GMAC $320k?

Tags: fargo

In the movie *Fargo*, automobile sales manager Jerry Lundegard owes $320,000 to GMAC, due to loans he has made for fictitious vehicles.  At the same time, he arranges for his wife to be kidnapped for $80,000, with the kidnappers getting half of that ransom and the other half going to Jerry.

**Why did Jerry ask for less ransom money than he owed?**  He could have easily asked for more -- he knows his father-in-law can afford it -- and gotten himself out of his mess with GMAC.  (Indeed, he even tries unsuccessfully to call off the kidnapping after he finds a $750,000 scheme.)

Looking for an in-universe answer.  Of course, the out-of-universe answer is that it helps to show how pathetic he is.

---

Related, but does not address the mismatch in the numbers: [Is there any hint as to why Jerry needs the money?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/18864/65120)

Answer (score 15):

Part of Jerry’s scheme is to embezzle the ransom. He tells the kidnappers (Steve Buscemi and Peter Stormare’s characters) that the ransom is $80k, and they will receive a cut from it plus the tan Sierra. He tells Wade that the kidnappers have asked for $1 million.

His whole scheme is upended when Wade refuses to let Jerry be the one who hands off the ransom (“it’s my money!”) and does it himself.  The funny-looking fella is surprised to see Wade, ends up killing him, and is then even more surprised to find $920k more than he’d expected in the briefcase. He buries the extra money in the snow as a way of concealing it from his partner.